# Facebook API check granted or declined permissions in Cordova

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, cordova-plugins

I am using this plugin https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4 and I tried doing

```
facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me/permissions', function(response) {
  var declined = [];
  for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) { 
    if (response.data[i].status == 'declined') {
      declined.push(response.data[i].permission)
    }
  }
  console.log(declined.toString());
},function error(error){console.log(error)});
```

But this doesn't work because it just console.logs the values but doesn't allow me to do anything with the response. Even if I take out the success callback, it still prints the response. I just can't use the value for some reason.